# How to refresh associated documents (previously populated) in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a Game model and a Player model. A game has an array of referenced players.

Inside of a game method one of the players is modified (not directly through this association instances but elsewhere). However, still inside the method, the version of the modified player data I have on `this.players` is outdated, from before the modification.

I am using mongoose-autopopulate. I tried calling `this.populate('players')` again but the array is not updated. I was wondering whether there is a way to refresh the association so I have the updated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting autopopulate in the Schema so it always populates the attributes I want automatically. Something like that:

```
const gameSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String, 
    players: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Player',
        autopopulate: { maxDepth: 2 }
    }],

...
```